# Laravel: Date between with zero values

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm trying to get database values for a given date-range. The problem is, that I'm also trying to achieve to get missing values. If I have values for day 1 and 3, and I ask for the values for the days 1-5 I want to get something like this:

1 -> Value

2 -> NULL / 0

3 -> Value

4 -> NULL / 0

5 -> NULL / 0

Ok, I know how to solve this problem using just MySQL and this temporary table in a left join:

```
(select adddate('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) selected_date from                                                                                            
    (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union  select 8 union select 9) t0,
    (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
    (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
    (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
    (select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
```

Unfortunatly I'm not sure how to include this in Eloquent ORM.
Currently I'm thinking of something like this:

```
$weekclockings = $shift->clockings()->leftJoin(function($query)
{                                                                   
    $query->raw($aboveQuery);
}, "v.selected_date", ">", "timeclocked.time_in")
```

but this doesn't work and just gives me "ErrorException in Grammar.php line 33: Object of class Closure could not be converted to string".

So, probably this isn't even the best way to do it. Has anyone an idea how to achieve this?

Comment: I do not get the part where you mix (order? of) day value with date value. How can anyone distinguish what should be put in range when null is allowed? I mean if you know the days you want to get just use simple where and order it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what is `clockings()` here - probably a scope, but to use raw SQL in join, you should use:

```
$weekclockings = $shift->clockings()->leftJoin(\DB::raw($aboveQuery), "v.selected_date", ">", "timeclocked.time_in");
```